# Running spark job using Yarn giving error:com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, classpath, hadoop-yarn

I am trying run spark job using yarn,but getting below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback;Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initAsync(Connection.java:176)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:721)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:248)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:194)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:82)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1307)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:249)
at com.figmd.processor.ProblemDataloader$ParseJson.call(ProblemDataloader.java:46)
at com.figmd.processor.ProblemDataloader$ParseJson.call(ProblemDataloader.java:34)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$4$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$fn$4$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:140)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:618)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:247)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

cluster Details:
Spark 1.2.1,hadoop 2.7.1
I have provided class path using spark.driver.extraClassPath.
hadoop user has access to that class path as well.But I think yarn is not getting the JAR's on that classpath.
I am not able to reach root cause of it.Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked your YARN cluster properly, i guess its already having some version of Guava jar and in your fat jar you have latest version, which is overridden by YARN Cluster jar.

Comment: Sorry,but may I know where I can check for YARN cluster jar?and I think yar is not getting any of the jar on spark classpath provided by "spark.driver.extraClassPath" and "spark.executor.extraClassPath".Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and the solution was **shade guava** to avoid `classpath` collision.

If you're using [sbt assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#shading) to build your jar, you can just add this to your `build.sbt`:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shadeio.@1").inAll
)
```

I wrote a blog post which describes my process to arrive to this solution: [Making Hadoop 2.6 + Spark-Cassandra Driver Play Nice Together](http://arjon.es/2015/10/12/making-hadoop-2-dot-6-plus-spark-cassandra-driver-play-nice-together/).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Issue is related to guava version mismatch.

`withFallback` was added to version 14 of Guava. It looks like you have Guava < 14 on your classpath

Comment: No,I am using 16.0.1 version of Guava.

Comment: are you using fat jar??

Comment: Yes.And I have all required dependencies JAR on class path.

Comment: check maven dependency tree for older version of guava (mvn dependency:tree -Doutput=/path/to/file) or explode jar and decompile com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures

Comment: My issue was the same, some Hadoop component was using guava 11. once changed the pom.xml to suppress guava 11 it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Arjones answer, if you are using gradle + [GradleShadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow), you can add this to your build.gradle to relocate or rename the Guava classes.

```Java
shadowJar {
    relocate 'com.google.common', 'com.example.com.google.common'
}
```

Comment: What if I actually need guava for url parsing or something of the like?